# Deleted .xib Still Appears Xcode 5 OSX Development

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, caching

While working on an OSX app, I created a .xib file that I have since deleted. I clicked the "move to trash" option, not just "remove reference". I also took the following steps:

- Delete the project created by running the app
- Clean the project (cmd-shift-k)
- Clean the project's build folder (cmd-shift-opt-k)
- Delete the derived data folder at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Delete everything within /var/folder
- Restart Xcode

Yet when restarting Xcode and running the app, the window from the deleted .xib still appears. Any ideas how to get rid of this damn thing? I'm using OSX 10.9.2 and Xcode 5.1.

Comment: Can you check to see if the xib's filename still appears in project.pbxproj or anywhere in the project name.xcodeproj/ directory?  Maybe grep at the root of the project?

Comment: The .xib was completely gone, but somehow a window persisted in MainMenu.xib (see my answer below). I must have accidentally added a window to MainMenu that I mistook for the deleted .xib. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

The window persisted in the side panel of MainMenu.xib. As can be seen, I have a window called "Bean Api Example". The window that wouldn't go away was also listed there. Once I deleted that listing, the window no longer appeared when running the app.

I'm not sure how that window appeared on the side panel in the first place, as creating a new xib with a window did not list a window in MainMenu.xib.

[image: Interface Builder Side Panel]